# Javascript ButtonClick issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Currently workin on a auction-site where I want a "buy-out" button for the impatient people ready to pay more to get their object right away. Below is the code so far but I am having some issues (in Chrome at least) where first of all the popup for confirmation is not showing up since I tried to get the buy-out value in the textbox. But the rest of the code goes through (The buy-out bid is put and the auction timer starts counting down) but this means you could click it by mistake right now. I assume the issues is in how I should access the buy-out price in the confirmation textbox. Any help would be apprechiated!

HTML

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="BuyNowButton" OnClick="BuyNowButton_Click" Style="vertical-    align:top;" ImageUrl="Images/btn_buyNow.png" runat="server" OnClientClick="var buyOutPrice =     Content.ReservationPrice; javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to buy-out the auction for  $' + 'buyOutPrice' + '?'); BuyNow(); return ValidateBuyNow();" />
```

Script

```
function ValidateBuyNow() {
    var amount = CurrentBidValue.value;
    if (amount >= (parseInt(HighestBid) + parseInt('<%=Content.Bid.LowestBidRaise %>'))) {
        HighestBid = amount;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


function BuyNow() {
    CurrentBidValue = parseInt('<%=Content.ReservationPrice %>');
}
```

Comment: why are you not use JQuery?
Its is to easy to get get textbox value and fire button event in JQuery.

Comment: I haven't really used JQuery alot.

Answer (score 0):

At very first sight, you need to change this

```
var amount = CurrentBidValue.value;
```

by

```
var amount = CurrentBidValue;
```

So far I see on the code, the variable `CurrentBidValue` contains a number (`CurrentBidValue = parseInt('...')`) so there is no `value` property

Also, if `Content.Bid.LowestBidRaise` and `Content.ReservationPrice` are numbers you can simlify a little your code and do

```
(parseInt(HighestBid) + <%=Content.Bid.LowestBidRaise %>)
```

and

```
CurrentBidValue = <%=Content.ReservationPrice %>
```

Comment: While all of those were valid changes, they didn't change the fact that I can't get the number I want in the textbox.